# Entity Framework Core One to Many: Unable to determine the relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, relationship

I want to create a relationship between two models. On EF migration add I got the the following error:

https://pastebin.com/xzBUN0qn

Here is my code, I didn't use fluent.

```
[Table("Teams")]
public class TeamModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TeamType Type { get; set; }
    public TeamSubType SubType { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<CharacterModel> Members { get; set; }
}

[Table("Characters")]
public class CharacterModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; }

    public TeamRanks? FactionRank { get; set; }
    public TeamRanks? GroupRank { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public double PosX { get; set; }
    public double PosY { get; set; }
    public double PosZ { get; set; }

    public TeamModel Faction { get; set; }
    public TeamModel Group { get; set; }
}
```

The first line of the exception message reads:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'CharacterModel.Faction' of type 'TeamModel'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Comment: can you please copy paste the error to question. Some of us can't open external websites.

Comment: I assume you have a one-to-many relationship between TeamModel and CharacterModel. The error is self-explanatory. Since, you decorated the Members collection on TeamModel with the [NotMapped] attribute it can't seem to determine the relationship between two models. You can remove the attribute and give it a try.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `[ForignKey("")]` attribute to the `Faction` property?

Comment: @JamieRees "Foreign key constraint names cannot be configured using data annotations." source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints